# Overriding spring properties in application.properties that is part of a jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar, spring-cloud

I'm developing a spring boot application(Let's call this MyLib). It uses spring-cloud-stream. The idea is that this application will be used as a jar by another java application(Let's call this MyApp. It may not be a spring boot). What I'm trying to do is that MyApp will specify the `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channel>.destination` which will be used by the code inside MyLib.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Load application.properties from an external jar

I don't know about `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` specifically, however a spring Boot application can load its `application-${profile}.properties` from multiple locations including jars on the classpath:

[Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties
>   files in the following locations and add them to the Spring
>   Environment:
>
> - A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - **A classpath /config package**
> - **The classpath root**
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations
>   higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).
>
> ...
>
> The default search path
>   classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/ is always used,
>   irrespective of the value of spring.config.location

In other words, the `application-${profile}.properties` file must be at `./` or `./config/` inside your `MyApp.jar`.

You may also define additional lookup folders with `spring.config.location`, however this must be done at runtime:

> `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` are used very early to determine which files
>   have to be loaded so they have to be defined as an environment
>   property (typically OS env, system property or command line argument).

---

### Lookup order

You mentioned 
:

> Overriding spring properties in application.properties

The order with which the properties are considered is the following ([from spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)):

> - @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
> - Command line arguments.
> - Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property)
> - ServletConfig init parameters.
> - ServletContext init parameters.
> - JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> - Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> - OS environment variables.
> - A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
> - **Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)**
> - **Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)**
> - **Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).**
> - **Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).**
> - @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> - Default properties (specified using SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).